# controlling of iphone camera shutterspeed

Tags: iphone

How to build an application like slowshutter?
my exact question is how to control shutter speed of ios camera as they did in this application.

Answer (score 3):

The digital iPhone camera does not have any shutter. Shutter speed is a common term used to express exposure time, which cannot be changed on the iPhone camera. Slowshutter basically takes multiple pictures during the set exposure time and merges those images into one image (light trail function). The first picture is displayed entirely and the following pictures are displayed incrementally on top.

For example, let's say the iPhone took three photo's during the set exposure time:

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]

The first picture is used entirely and the following only incremental:

[image: 1]
[image: 2 2]
[image: 3 2]

Which results into the following:

[image: 4]

If the shutter is set to 5 seconds you take 25 pictures, every 200 millisecond one.
Merge the pictures like described above and your are done :)

The `GPUImage` project might simplify implementation:
https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage
http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/2012/02/12/introducing-gpuimage-framework